# java setting a variable

Tags: java, variables, colors

I am having some trouble with the code below. My problem is that the variable `BGCLRFORPNLS` doesn't take the same value as the variable `c`. But it should work because this variable is a reference.

```
public static Color BGCLRFORPNLS = Color.BLACK;
private static void Initialze() {
    List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    colors.add(BGCLRFORPNLS);
    Color c = colors.get(0);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hashcode of c: "+ c.hashCode());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hashcode of BGCLRFORPNLS: "+ BGCLRFORPNLS.hashCode());

    c = Color.red;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "color of c: "+ c.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "color of BGCLRFORPNLS: "+ BGCLRFORPNLS.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't work since `c` is a reference to a `Color` object, when you change it, you don't change any other reference to the object and you don't change the value of the object, but only the specific reference.

```
statement                   |  BGCLRFORPNLS |     colors[0]     |     c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BGCLRFORPNLS = Color.BLACK; |  Color.BLACK  |     ----          |      ------
colors.add(BGCLRFORPNLS);   |  Color.BLACK  |    Color.BLACK    |      ------
Color c = colors.get(0);    |  Color.BLACK  |    Color.BLACK    |   Color.BLACK
c = Color.red;              |  Color.BLACK  |    Color.BLACK    |   Color.red
```

Comment: jip I understand but is there then an other way so it would work? any sugestions?

Comment: @user744329, if you want to change the value of BGCLRFORPNLS, you have to do something like BGCLRFORPNLS = Color.red . BGCLRFORPNLS is not final, thus you can change the value. But maybe you should expand on what you're really trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply changing the reference, i.e. you are having the reference c point to the object Red. This has absolutely no side effects on the object you previously referenced.